# split a double quoted string in ruby on a backslash

Tags: ruby, string, magento

I need to split a string by the backslash, the problem is that when I have something like '\n' inside de string, it is not recognized. I found that this occurs because the double quoted string interprets the \n as a new line char.

example

```
irb(main):109:0> 'testestet\nehcucahu'.split('\\')
=> ["testestet", "nehcucahu"] # <---- this is what I want
irb(main):110:0> "testestet\nehcucahu".split('\\')
=> ["testestet\nehcucahu"]
```

Can I convert a double quoted string to a single quoted before calling split? Or there is another way achieve the desired behavior?

**EDIT**

Further work showed me that magento inserts a '\n' for every line on street, which make a lot more sense. I could split it on this specific situation using .split(/\n/). the comments below have better information if you need to split at a backslash

Comment: What you want is what you get. Are you sure you didn't double-quote the string?  Please double-check.

Comment: I have to recover this as a attribute `irb(main):131:0> a.street
=> "rua rua urua\nhuhuhucuhch"`. This attribute is saved to the database based on a response of a webservice (magento), I have no control over what the user inputs here and whats get saved, but I could clean it when saving to the rails database, there is a way of cleaning it?

Comment: When you have a double-quoted string such as `str = "rua rua urua\nhuhuhucuhch"`, you obviously cannot split on backslashes because it contains none.  The selected answer finds a way: convert each newline to a backslash followed by `"n"`, then split on backslashes.  I just wanted to point out that that has *nothing* to do with backslashes. We could replace the newlines with any string not in the string, plus `"n"`, then split on that string. For example, `str.gsub(/\n/,'9n').split('9') #=>  ["testestet", "nehcucahu"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you replace the newlines first and then split?

`str.gsub(/\n/,"\\n").split(/\\/)`

Comment: this worked, but how can I prevent the problem for others special chars?

Comment: EDIT - I changed to this: `a.street.gsub(/[\t\r\n\f]/,"\\n").split(/\\/)`, and it seems to cover everything I might encounter on a text field! but it has a bug where it changes the letter after the backslash to "n" EDIT -- final code `a.street.split(/[\t\r\n\f\\]/)`, I wont mind lose one letter

Comment: Are you sure you want to translate these escape characters into letters and not just split on them? If you definitely do, you could replace them all individually something like this `"a\tb\nc\rd\f".gsub(/[\t\n\r\f]/,{"\t"=>"\\t","\r"=>"\\r","\n"=>"\\n","\f"=>"\\f"}).split(/\\/)` which produces `["a", "tb", "nc", "rd", "f"]`

Answer (score 1):

This is all about single-quoted versus double-quoted strings.

The string `a.street` you mentioned in a comment, which I'll call

```
str = "rua rua urua\nhuhuhucuhch"
```

contains a newline character at offset 12:

```
str.index("\n") => 12
```

and does not contain a backslash:

```
str.index("\\") #=> nil
```

so you can't split on a backslash.

If this string had been in single quotes (as is the string in your question):

```
str = 'rua rua urua\nhuhuhucuhch'
str.split("\\") #=> ["rua rua urua", "nhuhuhucuhch"]`.
```

That's because `str` now contains a backslash, followed by an `"n"`, but no newline:

```
str.index("\\") #=> 12 
str.index("n")  #=> 13 
str.index("\n") #=> nil
```